# How can I build a simple website that contains SQL injection vulnerabilities?

Tags: sql-injection, websites

How can I build a simple website that contains SQL injection vulnerabilities for study purposes? What do I need to learn?

Comment: Do you know how to make a website? Do you know how to make a web app that uses SQL? Do you know how to code SQLi vulnerabilities?

Comment: By not using parametrized queries and not doing user input data sanitation.

Answer (score 2):

There's an app for that. See https://owasp.org/www-project-juice-shop/

It's a project designed to break all the rules, so you can study it. You can try and find all the problems, not only sql-injection.

Comment: Plus many, many other hackable VMs, apps, etc.